# Creating own shortcode - echoeing php variable based on JS variable

Tags: php, shortcode, javascript

I am trying to create a simple shortcode which allows me to display on a page a dropdown list and based on the chosen option it should display a specific contact form.

The shortcode on the backend:
**[formularze form="561,559,560" name="Form 1, Form 2, Form 3"]**
The "form" attribute is the contact form 7 ID, the "name" attribute is a name for a dropdown list.

The code:

```
function formularze_func( $atts ) {
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'form' => '',
    'name' => '',
), $atts );

$form = $a['form'];
$name = $a['name'];

$ids_array = explode(',', $form);
$names_array = explode(',', $name);

$dropdown = "<select id=\"selectForm\">";
for($i=0;$i<count($ids_array);$i++) {
    $dropdown .= "<option value=\"";
    $dropdown .= $i;
    $dropdown .= "\">";
    $dropdown .= $names_array[$i];
    $dropdown .= "</option>";    
}
$dropdown .= "</select>";

$formDiv = "<div id=\"form\"></div>";

$formDisplay = "
         <script>
        var dropdown = document.getElementById(\"selectForm\");
        var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        var formId = " . json_encode($ids_array(\\\\TOTALLY STUCK HERE\\\\)) . "
        document.getElementById(\"form\").innerHTML = \"[contact-form-7 id=\"formId\"]\";
    </script> 

";


$ready = $dropdown . $formDiv . $formDisplay;

if( count($ids_array) == count($names_array) ) {
    return $ready;
} else return "Error.";
}
add_shortcode( 'formularze', 'formularze_func' );
```

The code isn't maybe the prettiest in the world so I would be glad for any improvement.

The problem is in this place - \\TOTALLY STUCK HERE\\
How can I pass there the JS variable **value**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add logic for changing in that way. You need react on user "front-end" event with js.

Also this construction will work wrong:

```
 document.getElementById(\"form\").innerHTML = \"[contact-form-7 id=\"formId\"]\";
```

Will be always print [contact-form-7 id=\"formId\"], because js can't do_shortcode function itself.

If you wanna make it simple(without ajax process) you need:

1) Print all forms with php and style "display: none;"

2) Add [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event for select

3) On change options "show" needed form

Quick example how print forms:

```
 $formDivs = '';
    forearch($ids_array as $i=>$id) {
      $formDivs .= do_shortcode("<div id=\"form_{$i}\" style="display: none;">[contact-form-7 id=\"{$id}\"]</div>");
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. It seems easier than my first thought, however, I can't get it working :( The JS code seems to fail, because the dropdown doesn't react at all.
Here's the codepen, I hope you don;t mind: https://codepen.io/dandy7/pen/LLXwPK

Comment: I make fork with fix for you! Check it please https://codepen.io/flinius/pen/weQVoq

Comment: Also add please logic for make invisible all others form onchange :)